# Seleccionar mas de un checkbox en una lista

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, checkbox

Tengo una aplicación para encuestas en react, y debo mostrar las respuestas posibles al usuario en checkboxs para que elija una, el problema es que no me deja seleccionar un checkbox por pregunta.
La info la cargo desde una Api y la mapeo en una lista HTML.

[Aqui](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-controlled-checkbox-list-forked-w3sgt?file=/src/index.js) dejo mi código

Comment: Si es para elegir sólo una opción, lo apropiado es usar botones radio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que relacionar los checkboxs entre sí pasándoles el atributo `name`.

En este caso le podemos agregar a cada elemento de los arrays `listaRes`, la propiedad `name` así:

```
const preguntas = [
{
  idEncuesta: 7,
  encuesta: "Encuesta2 ",
  idPregunta: 26,
  pregunta: "¿Que tan probable es que le recomiende su jefe/a a un colega?",
  listaRes: [
    {
      idRelacion: 1,
      idPregunta: 27,
      idRespuesta: 1,
      respuesta: "Muy probable",
      name: 1
    },
    {
      idRelacion: 2,
      idPregunta: 27,
      idRespuesta: 2,
      respuesta: "Nada probable",
      name: 1
    }
  ]
},
{
  idEncuesta: 7,
  encuesta: "Encuesta2",
  idPregunta: 27,
  pregunta:
    "¿Qué tan fácil es obtener ayuda de su jefe/a cuando la necesita?",
  listaRes: [
    {
      idRelacion: 3,
      idPregunta: 27,
      idRespuesta: 3,
      respuesta: "Nada facil",
      name: 2
    },
    {
      idRelacion: 4,
      idPregunta: 27,
      idRespuesta: 4,
      respuesta: "No tan facil",
      name: 2
    },
    {
      idRelacion: 5,
      idPregunta: 27,
      idRespuesta: 5,
      respuesta: "Algo facil",
      name: 2
    },
    {
      idRelacion: 6,
      idPregunta: 27,
      idRespuesta: 6,
      respuesta: "Muy facil",
      name: 2
    },
    {
      idRelacion: 7,
      idPregunta: 27,
      idRespuesta: 7,
      respuesta: "Extremadamente facil",
      name: 2
    }
  ]
},
{
  idEncuesta: 7,
  encuesta: "Encuesta2",
  idPregunta: 28,
  pregunta: "¿Qué tan disponible para los empleados esta su jefe?",
  listaRes: [
    {
      idRelacion: 8,
      idPregunta: 28,
      idRespuesta: 8,
      respuesta: "Nada disponible",
      name: 3
    },
    {
      idRelacion: 9,
      idPregunta: 28,
      idRespuesta: 9,
      respuesta: "Poco disponible",
      name: 3
    },
    {
      idRelacion: 10,
      idPregunta: 28,
      idRespuesta: 10,
      respuesta: "Moderadamente disponible",
      name: 3
    },
    {
      idRelacion: 11,
      idPregunta: 28,
      idRespuesta: 11,
      respuesta: "Muy disponible",
      name: 3
    },
    {
      idRelacion: 12,
      idPregunta: 28,
      idRespuesta: 12,
      respuesta: "Extremadamente disponible",
      name: 3
    }
  ]
}
];
```

Luego al hacer el `.map`, en el atributo `name` del `<input>` le pasamos la nueva propiedad:

```
name={subitem.name}
```

Nos quedaría así:

```
<input
  className="form-check-input"
  type="radio"
  name={subitem.name}
  defaultValue={subitem.idRelacion}
  onChange={handleChange}
 ></input>
```

Y de esa forma se puede seleccionar solo un checkbox por pregunta.